# Allow customer to choose an optional free/paid product to add to their order (and reduce stock reduced & record sale)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

was wondering if there is a way (or plugin) that would allow me to add functionality similar to other sites where a user can choose a product say a skateboard deck, and can optionally choose griptape from a select to add to the order (This is on the product page btw, not checkout page yet).
Example - note the "Griptape" section:

[image: Note the "Griptape" line]

After choosing the griptape and adding the product to their cart, and the order is complete, the stock for both the deck and the chosen griptape should be reduced and the purchase/sale of each individual item recorded as well.

Hopefully I've explained it well but is there a plugin or way to get this done?

Comment: Would setting up your product as a Variable product be an option? The variable options could be set as 'skateboard', 'skateboard + grip tape', 'skateboard + grip tape + trucks', ect... 'https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: @italiansoda not quite since Variable Products use attributes to create the variations and don't link to actual products or handle stock either. I check around and found the Chained Products plugin and this is *mostly* what I want except for the fact it seems to give you *all* the chained products you specify and doesn't let you choose just one from a list...